# Why is log$(\frac{G}{a})+\frac{a}{G} \geq 1$

Tags: analysis

I am currently trying to understand Alzers proof of the arithmetic mean geometric-mean inequality. ([Link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974672?searchText=&searchUri=&ab_segments=&searchKey=&refreqid=fastly-default%3A82b9da81a0830903f91783d63d0645c8))

It states that for $a\displaystyle_i, p_i \in \mathbb{R} \;  \text{with} \sum p_i =1\text{ and }\mathbf{G}:= \prod a_i^{p_i}$ there exists an $k \;$ such that $a_k \leq \mathbf{G} \leq a_{k+1}$. 
With this information it is now said, that $\displaystyle\int_{a_i}^{\mathbf{G}} \left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\mathbf{G}}\right) \mathrm{d}t \geq 0 \; \;  \forall i \leq k$.

When integrating I get

$$\log\left(\dfrac{G}{a_i}\right) -1 + \dfrac{a_i}{G} \geq 0$$

I ofc. know, that $\log\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{G}}{a_i}\right)\geq0$.

The proof seems so obvious but I can't figure it out and it drives me crazy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: With $x=a/G$ this is equivalent to $-\log(x) + x \ge 1$, or $\log(x) \le x-1$, which is a well-known inequality, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188910/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prove $\log(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396776/prove-log1xx-for-x0)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was what I was looking for